# Conjugação após “em vez de”

Tags: gramática, concordância-verbal, infinitivo-pessoal

Ao indicar uma alternativa usando “em vez de”, a conjugação do verbo se mantém no presente do indicativo ou ela retorna ao infinitivo?

Exemplo:

- “Pessoas compram em vez de alugam.”
- “Pessoas compram em vez de alugar.”

Qual das duas formas é preferida?

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE, villasv! Obrigado por contribuir. Alterei o título da pergunta para que ele, ao meu ver, reflita melhor o conteúdo, mas se discordar, sinta-se à vontade para desfazer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Usamos o infinitivo](https://falarportugues.net/infinitivo-pessoal-em-portugues/) depois de preposições ou [locuções prepositivas](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf82.php) (como "em vez de" ou "ao invés de"), portanto:

> Pessoas compram em vez de alugar.

A escolha que então nos resta é entre o infinitivo pessoal (i.e., conjugado, "alugarem") ou impessoal ("alugar") e a decisão pode ser tomada considerando-se dois pontos:

1. via de regra usa-se o infinitivo *impessoal*, mas
2. em prol da clareza (com relação ao sujeito) o infinitivo *pessoal* pode ser preferível.

A situação típica em que convém concordar o infinitivo com o sujeito é aquela em que a oração subordinada alternativa (i.e., com "em vez de") antecede a principal:

> Em vez de alugarem, as pessoas compram.

Fontes adicionais:

- https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf70.php
- https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/em-virtude-de--infinitivo/18516
- http://www3.uol.com.br/qualidadeconteudo/portugues/infinitivo-anteposto-a-verbo-principal-concorda-com-o-sujeito.jhtm
- https://falarportugues.net/infinitivo-pessoal-em-portugues/